# PyCharm can't import module

Tags: python, linux, pycharm

I am using PyCharm on a Linux machine. Usually, when I import a module, eg. OpenCV or numpy, it works just fine. But when I try to import gphoto2, I get the following error.

```
Collecting gphoto2
  Using cached gphoto2-2.2.2.tar.gz (1.9 MB)

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/anders/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pycharm-packaging/gphoto2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pycharm-packaging/gphoto2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-srufwxku
         cwd: /tmp/pycharm-packaging/gphoto2/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    ERROR: command "pkg-config --modversion libgphoto2" failed
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging/gphoto2/setup.py", line 36, in <module>
        cmd, stderr=FNULL, universal_newlines=True).split('.')[:3]
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
        output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkg-config', '--modversion', 'libgphoto2']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: I think this is related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83616/pip-error-trying-to-get-gphoto-lib

Comment: I tried installing libgphoto2-dev but the problemer persist.